# git wont add directories

Tags: git

I am having trouble getting subdirectories to update to commit so I can push them.

My main directory is projects and this is where I created my init to manage a few small projects into one git repo.

I created a directory and a virtualenv and put it into git.

so currently I have

```
-Project
        ->flask-blog/
                    fb/
                      /bin
                      /include
                      /lib
```

I then added blog.py and a static and templates directories into my folder.

```
-Project
        ->flask-blog/
                    fb/
                       /bin
                       /include
                       /lib
                    static/
                    templates/
                    blog.py
```

I then added them to git from the project folder.

```
git add .
```

But that didn't work, well it added blog.py but not the new directories. So I tried.

```
git add -A
```

and

```
git add *
```

and

```
git add flask-blog/*
```

but none of these have worked how to I get git to notice my new directories?

Comment: Git never tracks directories, only files; this is nothing Python specific. Put dummy files in such directories if you want them to be added to the git repo.

Comment: @Martin Pieters.    Thanks why would git not do something so basic?

Comment: Because directories don't need tracking; there are no versions of directories, only versions of files contained in directories.